# Passing content values form one activity to another in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio

Activity1

```
private Cursor model = null;
private ClientAdapter adapter = null;
private ClientHelper helper = null;
private SharedPreferences prefs = null;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adapters;
private ArrayAdapter<String> adaptera;
private String[] available_locations;
private String[] selected_locations;
private ListView list1;
private ListView list2;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.locations);

    list1 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.available_locations);
    list2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.selected_locations);
    available_locations = getIntent().getStringExtra("List");
    .....
```

Activity 2

```
....
public String getID(Cursor c) {
    return (c.getString(0));
}

public String getclientName(Cursor c) {
    return (c.getString(1));
}

public String getAddress(Cursor c) {
    return (c.getString(2));
}

public String getTelephone(Cursor c) {
    return (c.getString(3));
}

public String getCuisineType(Cursor c) {
    return (c.getString(4));
}

public double getLatitude(Cursor c) {
    return (c.getDouble(5));
}

public double getLongitude(Cursor c) {
    return (c.getDouble(6));
}

public ArrayList<String> getclient;
getclient.add("clientName");
getclient.add("Address");
getclient.add("Telephone");
getclient.add("cuisineType");
getclient.add("lat");
getclient.add("lon");
public Intent intenti;
intenti = new Intent(ClientHelper.this, SetDestination.class);
intenti.putExtra("List", getclient);
startactivity(intenti);
```

How do I pass information from Activity2 to Activity1?

I want to do a Listview where I can select clients from the list that I have already added (hence two activity, list1 and list2, in activity1)

Answer (score 0):

Use can use the Bundle to pass the data from one activity to other.

First make the object parcelable.You can do that using the plugin of Parcelable in android studio.

Example.
        Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(),targetclassname.class);
        HomeScreenData homeScreenData=new HomeScreenData();//Pojo class 
        intent.putExtra("categorydesc",homeScreenData);
       startActivity(intent);

```
{
//Pojo Class`enter code here`
public class HomeScreenData implements Parcelable {
private String imagePath;
private String imageTitle;

public String getImagePath() {
    return imagePath;
}

public void setImagePath(String imagePath) {
    this.imagePath = imagePath;
}

public String getImageTitle() {
    return imageTitle;
}

public void setImageTitle(String imageTitle) {
    this.imageTitle = imageTitle;
}


@Override
public int describeContents() {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(this.imagePath);
    dest.writeString(this.imageTitle);
}

public HomeScreenData() {
}

protected HomeScreenData(Parcel in) {
    this.imagePath = in.readString();
    this.imageTitle = in.readString();
}

public static final Parcelable.Creator<HomeScreenData> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<HomeScreenData>() {
    public HomeScreenData createFromParcel(Parcel source) {
        return new HomeScreenData(source);
    }

    public HomeScreenData[] newArray(int size) {
        return new HomeScreenData[size];
    }
};
```

}